# How to get bitbucket repositories list?

Tags: java, repository, bitbucket

Can someone please tell me how to get list of bitbucket repositories, I am accessing this URL

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}
```

But when I hit this URL I am getting this kind of JSON

```
{
    "pagelen": 10,
    "values": [],
    "page": 1,
    "size": 0
}
```

And I am sure this is not what I wanted. Is there any header parameters need to be set or something because I am not setting any header parameter, Only using above URL with **GET** method. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From Atlassian's own [documentation](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/how-can-i-query-the-bitbucket-rest-api-for-all-repositories/qaq-p/158964), this currently does not appear to be possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reply but seems like the documentation is of 2016, So still Atlassian haven't implemented that?

Comment: You may answer your own question if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved something now, You can get repository list but you need access_token as well. You can refer [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/) for that.

Hope this will work for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use curl for retrieving the repos

> curl --user username:password --insecur GET
>   http://localhost:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/WORK/repos | jq
>   --raw-output '.values[].slug'

Answer (score 1):

curl alone will only fetch you 10 results per API call, which gets tedious if you have lots of repositories.

Here's a small script that drills down to as many pages as you need, and additionally extracts the organization, description, and whether the repository is private or not. The  `?role=member` parameter lists all repositories you have access to.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Bitbucket Username (not email): ' BB_USERNAME
read -sp 'Bitbucket Password: ' BB_PASSWORD

next_url="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories?role=member"
while [ ! -z "$next_url" ]; do
    response_json=$( curl -s --user $BB_USERNAME:$BB_PASSWORD "$next_url" )
    echo "$response_json" | jq -r '.values | map([.slug, .workspace.slug, .description, .is_private] | @csv) | join("\n")'
    next_url=$( echo "$response_json" | jq -r '.next' )
done
```

Or if you prefer not to create a shell script, you can copy and paste this into your command line (replace YOUR_USERNAME and YOUR_PASSWORD with your own Bitbucket login details of course):

```
(
next_url="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories?role=member"
while [ ! -z "$next_url" ]; do
    response_json=$( curl -s --user YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_PASSWORD "$next_url" )
    echo "$response_json" | jq -r '.values | map([.slug, .workspace.slug, .description, .is_private] | @csv) | join("\n")'
    next_url=$( echo "$response_json" | jq -r '.next' )
done
)
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812839/81269 for pointing me in this direction.